# Uncaught Swift_TransportException cannot be solved

Tags: php, sql, bootstrap-4

I was trying to set up a signin/signup section on my website and I found a github account with codes that satisfy my target.[These are the github files](https://github.com/SinghDigamber/php-user-authentication) . Anyway, so the target was that when user is registering a new account, the user must fill [this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dD4L.png). When he clicks 'signup' after filling the form, an email has to be sent to the user with a token link for email verification. Now the problem is that for some reason, [this error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFBam.png), specifically the error "Uncaught Swift_TransportException". I assume there is some problem with the signup.php file and if so, then probably in this part:

```php
if($sqlQuery) {
  $msg = 'Click on the activation link to verify your email. <br><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/php-user-authentication-master/user_verificaiton.php?token='.$token.'"> Click here to verify email</a>
  ';

  // Create the Transport
  $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
  ->setUsername('your_email@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('your_email_password');

  // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
  $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

  // Create a message
  $message = (new Swift_Message('Please Verify Email Address!'))

  ->setFrom([$email => $firstname . ' ' . $lastname])
  ->setTo($email)
  ->addPart($msg, "text/html")
  ->setBody('Hello! User');

  // Send the message
  $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

if I set setUsername & setPassword as my email and password, then gmail gives me [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3BDW.png)

Or there is a problem in the AuthHandler.php as the error suggests:

```
                                    <?php

                                /*
                                * This file is part of SwiftMailer.
                                * (c) 2004-2009 Chris Corbyn
                                *
                                * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
                                * file that was distributed with this source code.
                                */

                                /**
                                 * An ESMTP handler for AUTH support (RFC 5248).
                                 *
                                 * @author Chris Corbyn
                                 */
                                class Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler implements Swift_Transport_EsmtpHandler
                                {
                                    /**
                                     * Authenticators available to process the request.
                                     *
                                     * @var Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Authenticator[]
                                     */
                                    private $authenticators = [];

                                    /**
                                     * The username for authentication.
                                     *
                                     * @var string
                                     */
                                    private $username;

                                    /**
                                     * The password for authentication.
                                     *
                                     * @var string
                                     */
                                    private $password;

                                    /**
                                     * The auth mode for authentication.
                                     *
                                     * @var string
                                     */
                                    private $auth_mode;

                                    /**
                                     * The ESMTP AUTH parameters available.
                                     *
                                     * @var string[]
                                     */
                                    private $esmtpParams = [];

                                    /**
                                     * Create a new AuthHandler with $authenticators for support.
                                     *
                                     * @param Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Authenticator[] $authenticators
                                     */
                                    public function __construct(array $authenticators)
                                    {
                                        $this->setAuthenticators($authenticators);
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Set the Authenticators which can process a login request.
                                     *
                                     * @param Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Authenticator[] $authenticators
                                     */
                                    public function setAuthenticators(array $authenticators)
                                    {
                                        $this->authenticators = $authenticators;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Get the Authenticators which can process a login request.
                                     *
                                     * @return Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Authenticator[]
                                     */
                                    public function getAuthenticators()
                                    {
                                        return $this->authenticators;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Set the username to authenticate with.
                                     *
                                     * @param string $username
                                     */
                                    public function setUsername($username)
                                    {
                                        $this->username = $username;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Get the username to authenticate with.
                                     *
                                     * @return string
                                     */
                                    public function getUsername()
                                    {
                                        return $this->username;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Set the password to authenticate with.
                                     *
                                     * @param string $password
                                     */
                                    public function setPassword($password)
                                    {
                                        $this->password = $password;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Get the password to authenticate with.
                                     *
                                     * @return string
                                     */
                                    public function getPassword()
                                    {
                                        return $this->password;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Set the auth mode to use to authenticate.
                                     *
                                     * @param string $mode
                                     */
                                    public function setAuthMode($mode)
                                    {
                                        $this->auth_mode = $mode;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Get the auth mode to use to authenticate.
                                     *
                                     * @return string
                                     */
                                    public function getAuthMode()
                                    {
                                        return $this->auth_mode;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Get the name of the ESMTP extension this handles.
                                     *
                                     * @return string
                                     */
                                    public function getHandledKeyword()
                                    {
                                        return 'AUTH';
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Set the parameters which the EHLO greeting indicated.
                                     *
                                     * @param string[] $parameters
                                     */
                                    public function setKeywordParams(array $parameters)
                                    {
                                        $this->esmtpParams = $parameters;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Runs immediately after a EHLO has been issued.
                                     *
                                     * @param Swift_Transport_SmtpAgent $agent to read/write
                                     */
                                    public function afterEhlo(Swift_Transport_SmtpAgent $agent)
                                    {
                                        if ($this->username) {
                                            $count = 0;
                                            $errors = [];
                                            foreach ($this->getAuthenticatorsForAgent() as $authenticator) {
                                                if (in_array(strtolower($authenticator->getAuthKeyword()), array_map('strtolower', $this->esmtpParams))) {
                                                    ++$count;
                                                    try {
                                                        if ($authenticator->authenticate($agent, $this->username, $this->password)) {
                                                            return;
                                                        }
                                                    } catch (Swift_TransportException $e) {
                                                        // keep the error message, but tries the other authenticators
                                                        $errors[] = [$authenticator->getAuthKeyword(), $e->getMessage()];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            $message = 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "'.$this->username.'" using '.$count.' possible authenticators.';
                                            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                                                $message .= ' Authenticator '.$error[0].' returned '.$error[1].'.';
                                            }
                                            throw new Swift_TransportException($message);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Not used.
                                     */
                                    public function getMailParams()
                                    {
                                        return [];
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Not used.
                                     */
                                    public function getRcptParams()
                                    {
                                        return [];
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Not used.
                                     */
                                    public function onCommand(Swift_Transport_SmtpAgent $agent, $command, $codes = [], &$failedRecipients = null, &$stop = false)
                                    {
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Returns +1, -1 or 0 according to the rules for usort().
                                     *
                                     * This method is called to ensure extensions can be execute in an appropriate order.
                                     *
                                     * @param string $esmtpKeyword to compare with
                                     *
                                     * @return int
                                     */
                                    public function getPriorityOver($esmtpKeyword)
                                    {
                                        return 0;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Returns an array of method names which are exposed to the Esmtp class.
                                     *
                                     * @return string[]
                                     */
                                    public function exposeMixinMethods()
                                    {
                                        return ['setUsername', 'getUsername', 'setPassword', 'getPassword', 'setAuthMode', 'getAuthMode'];
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Not used.
                                     */
                                    public function resetState()
                                    {
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Returns the authenticator list for the given agent.
                                     *
                                     * @return array
                                     */
                                    protected function getAuthenticatorsForAgent()
                                    {
                                        if (!$mode = strtolower($this->auth_mode)) {
                                            return $this->authenticators;
                                        }

                                        foreach ($this->authenticators as $authenticator) {
                                            if (strtolower($authenticator->getAuthKeyword()) == $mode) {
                                                return [$authenticator];
                                            }
                                        }

                                        throw new Swift_TransportException('Auth mode '.$mode.' is invalid');
                                    }
                                }
```

more specifically because if this in line 191:

```
throw new Swift_TransportException($message);
```

Can somebody tell me what is going wrong and how I can solve this?

Comment: Error messages are collected into `$message` and added to the exception. You've uploaded a picture of the text that contains a link to a solution.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am sorry, but I could not deduce the solution. What is the solution exactly?

Comment: I haven't checked the URL because it's a picture for me.